# Get employee's salary for each month

Tags: sql-server, telerik-reporting

I have 2 table `[EmployeeInfo]` `[EmployeeInfoHistory]` and I am storing salary of the employee in this table. I am able to get the salary of the employee against respective employee and stuff.

But I want to show employee's salary for every month like listed below.

My structure is for [EmployeeInfo]:

```
Create Table [EmployeeInfo]
(
  EmpID Int,
  Salary Int,
  EmployementStatus Varchar(50),
  HiringDate Date
);
```

My structure is for [EmployeeInfoHistory]:

```
Create Table [EmployeeInfoHistory]
(
  EmpID Int,
  NewSalary Int,
  UpdatedEmployementStatus Varchar(50),
  PromotionDate Date
);
```

Data for Info Table:

```
EmpID  Salary  Status   HiringDate
1      20000   Intern   2017-10-02
2      30000   Jr. DBA  2017-11-01
```

Data for InfoHistory Table:

```
EmpID  Salary  UpdatedStatus   PromotionDate
1      25000   Jr. DBA         2018-01-01
2      45000   Sr. DBA         2018-01-01
```

I want to list date in given format.

```
EmpID   Month     Salary  Status
1       October   20k     Intern
1       November  20k     Intern
1       December  20k     Intern
1       January   25k     Jr. DBA
2       November  30k     Jr. DBA
2       December  30k     Jr. DBA
2       January   45k     Sr. DBA
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: edit the question add some sample data would helpful.

Comment: without table structure its dificult to answer

Comment: I have updated the formatting and adding sample structure and data. Maybe this will help you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a table with dates. Here I've made a table using a CTE wich I join with your tables.

```
; WITH DS AS
(
    SELECT cast (Dateadd(year, -25, getdate()) AS date) as [Date]
        UNION all
    SELECT dateadd(Month, 1, [Date])
        FROM DS
        WHERE Date < getdate()
)
Select EMP.EmpID, DateName(month, DS.[Date]) as [Month], isnull(HIS.NewSalary, EMP.Salary) as Salary, ISNULL(HIS.UpdatedStatus, EMP.EmployementStatus) as [Status]
from EmployeeInfo as EMP
    inner join DS 
    on EMP.HiringDate <= DS.[Date]  
        left join EmployeeInfoHistory as HIS
        on HIS.EmpId = EMP.EmpID and HIS.PromotionDate <= DS.[Date]  
option(MaxRecursion 10000)
```

Comment: @Doonie Darkoo. It seems like you have deleted the EmployeeInfoHistory  table in your question, since I read it first... !?

Comment: Yes you get it right I thought it would be better to get a simple output first and later I'll move to that part because it was making me as well others confused how to tackle the situation. Anyhow it seems you have provided the solution for my previous question. Let me try it too.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask you again but can you do me a favor and please suggest me a solution against my given structure and data ?

Comment: It's the same Query, but without the EmployeeInfoHistory table.

Comment: @DoonieDarkoo please provide det original question, if you find my solution good, otherwise it will not give any meaning to others.

Comment: It worked. I've tried your solution and It worked. 
Let me make the question to old one. I really am glad you solved my biggest problem today. Love ya <3

Answer (score 0):

Get the `sum` of the data of `salary` column in the history table as for the required months corresponding to the employee id.